# Facebook,Google or Twitter Secret key

Tags: oauth, twitter-oauth, google-oauth

Can some one tell me the Secret and key for testing the Oauth authetication?

For Example , For Facebook

```
facebook {
            provider = org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
            key = ???????
            secret = ???????
            successUri = "/success.gsp"
            failureUri = "/failure.gsp"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No! It's a secret... I kid. You have to register an app at http://developer.facebook.com and you will get a key and a secret for your specific app.

Answer (score 0):

I have application which works in localhost environment. When i have registered my app on facebook a error occured " Wrong address "